# Can't call CMake from a Python script

Tags: python, cmake

I'm trying to call the [CMake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) command from a Python script. This is my code:

```
cmakeCmd = ["C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe",'-G Visual Studio 11 Win64', 'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\new\myProject']
retCode = subprocess.check_call(cmakeCmd, shell=True)
```

But I get the following output when running the script:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ochitaya\Desktop\New\myProj\sc.py", line 10, in <module>
    retCode = subprocess.check_call(cmakeCmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files\\CMake\x08in\\cmake.exe', '-G Visual Studio 11 Win64', 'C:\\Users\\ochitaya\\Desktop\new\\myProj']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A backslash (`\`) in a Python string is an escape character. That's why the string `"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"` is translated to `C:\\Program Files\\CMake\x08in\\cmake.exe` (notice that `\b` equals `\x08`). To fix this, tell Python you want the string to be read as-is, or in other words, as a **raw** string, by prefixing the string with `r`:

```
cmakeCmd = [r"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe",'-G Visual Studio 11 Win64', r'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\new\myProject']
```

For more on this topic, take a look at the official documentation on [string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: do you know what should i do if now it says:

Comment: mspdb110.dll is missing

Comment: @OvedChitayat Either you're missing that file, or that file cannot be found. Anyway, since that's a different question from this one, you should mark this one as closed and open a separate one for that question.